# How to extract date from calendar in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-activity, android-calendar

I am trying to make an event planner application in `Android`.  I have added the a calendar `widget` now what I want is that whenever a user clicks the add event button, It will go to a new `Activity` screen and the date selected by the user in the calendar in the previous `Activity` gets copied exactly to a text field.  Can anyone help me with this code?
P.S.-  I have added two `Fragments` on the main screen one for the calendar and one for the `Buttons`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean `DatePicker` then this is how you get selected date, by registering a date selection listener

```
datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Log.d("Date", "Year=" + year + " Month=" + (month + 1) + " day=" + dayOfMonth);

                }
            });
```

or you get the selected date anytime by :

```
 DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

or if you are using `CalendarView` then a simple `getDate()` call would do the trick. Now extract the day, month, year from that and pass it to the next activity via `Intent`

If you are using something else let us know.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Declaration

 private int mDay;
 private int mMonth;
 private int mYear;


// Creating click listener of button

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     // Getting values from DatePicker

     DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
     mDay = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
     mMonth = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
     mYear = datePicker.getYear();

    // Here you have to write the code to start new Activity
    // If your second activity name is "SecondActivity" then use below code

    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

    // Put the date values to the intent
    intent.putExtra("Day",mDay);
    intent.putExtra("Month",mMonth);
    intent.putExtra("Year",mYear);

    startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

**In Second `Activity`**

```
int day;
int month;
int year;

EditText dateEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    dateEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateEditText);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(intent != null){
         day = intent.getIntExtra("Day",0);
         month = intent.getIntExtra("Month",0);
         year = intent.getIntExtra("Year",0);

         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.set(2013,5,23);


         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
        dateEditText.setText(format.format(calendar.getTime()));

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

```
// If you are using Calendar View

calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView arg0, int year, int month,
    int date) {

     mDay = date;
     mYear = year;
     mMonth = month;
     // Now you can uses year, month date to sent 
}
```

});

```
 // Click Listener of Button in case of CalenderView

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Here you have to write the code to start new Activity
    // If your second activity name is "SecondActivity" then use below code

    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

    // Put the date values to the intent
    intent.putExtra("Day",mDay);
    intent.putExtra("Month",mMonth);
    intent.putExtra("Year",mYear);

    startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

Comment: I am using CalendarView.  Is this way also applicable to CalendarView?

Comment: I have updated my answer, and there are lots of example of `CalendarView`, `DatePcker` available online. You should search it and should try yourself instead of asking for complete code.

Comment: Thanx for that i tried many codes from online as well as from my own practice but failed to get the required thing done and then only i posted my own question . Will try more the next time. Thanx.. ☺